# Parsing of XML empty tags

Tags: java, eclipse, dom, domparser

I am using below the code to add new node to my XML file, but after parsing XML file the empty tags was removed.

Input : Input.xml

```xml
<company>
  <staff id="1">
    <user>8976</user>
    <status></status>
    <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
    <lastname>yong</lastname>
    <firstname>lee</firstname>
</company>
```

Code using for parsing(ADDING NEW TAG)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ModifyXMLFile2 {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

       try {
        String filepath = "c:\\input.xml";
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

        // Get the root element
        Node company = doc.getFirstChild();

        // Get the staff element , it may not working if tag has spaces, or
        // whatever weird characters in front...it's better to use
        // getElementsByTagName() to get it directly.
        // Node staff = company.getFirstChild();

        // Get the staff element by tag name directly
        Node staff = doc.getElementsByTagName("company").item(0);




        // append a new node to staff
        Element age = doc.createElement("level");
        age.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("3C"));
        staff.appendChild(age);


        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.out.println("Done");

       } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
       } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
       } catch (SAXException sae) {
        sae.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```xml
<company>
  <staff id="1">
    <user>8976</user>
    <status></status>
    <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
    <lastname>yong</lastname>
    <firstname>lee</firstname>
    <level>3C</level>
</company>
```

But I'm getting the output as

```xml
<company>
  <staff id="1">
    <user>8976</user>
    </status>
    <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
    <lastname>yong</lastname>
    <firstname>lee</firstname>
    <level>3C</level>
</company>
```

Status tag is not coming properly I need like `<status></status>` but I'm getting as `<status/>`.

Comment: In XML, `<status></status>` and `<status/>` mean the same thing, but the second is shorter. The second one is valid and no xml-compliant tool should have any problems reading the second output.

Comment: Which also means you have a typo in the question, either in the cited output, or the question itself.

Comment: Thank's for the responce, thats true In XML, <status></status> and <status/> mean the same thing  but as per my requirement i need 
<status></status>in output is there any way to get full term in output